# Can I fetch data from third-party MySql db using AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function to make CRUD operations on my DynamoDB database but I have to fetch data from third-party MySql database, normally in express/node. I do below and do operations on both db:

```
  // inside lambda function
  var mysqldata = require('./mysqldata') // here I read some data from third-party mysql db
  var dynamodbdata = require('./getMember')

  // here I do some operation to crud into dynamodb
```

But when I convert this to **serverless** I can write all the *dynamodbdata* in here and I can't do the same for mySQL DB

How can i solve this?

Comment: in short How can i make query to sqlDb on another url, while my server files are in aws

Comment: It sounds like you are having trouble connecting to a remote database on the Internet from your Lambda function. This is possible in theory, if the database is accessible from the Internet. Please provide details about the actual error or issue you are encountering.

Comment: Split out the the two database operations into two different lambdas and call them sequentially from the parent task. This separates the concerns of each lambda with a cleaner approach